# Elastic beanstalk automatically creates a security group that allows all traffic on port 80. How can I disable this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a service on Elastic Beanstalk (EB). When you create an EB environment, it asks you to select a security group for hosts running the application. No matter what you select, EB will always use your selected security group in addition to a generated security group which allows all external HTTP and HTTPS traffic on ports 80 and 443. Is there any way to disable this? I would like the allowed traffic to be determined by my selected security group. I do not want to allow any external traffic.

Answer (score 2):

**If your environment is using a Single Instance**

When a security group is created, you can always change this by going into EC2 **=>** Security Groups **=>** find the corresponding security group attached to the EC2 instance created by EB (probably some random characters like: `awseb-e-thmgihexyz-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-6PG13Z3VXXX9`) **=>** Inbound **=>** Edit **=>** remove `Inbound Port 80` and `Inbound Port 443`

Or a very similar method:

Go to EC2 **=>** select the instance that was created by your EB app **=>** scroll to the far left **=>** you'll see your security group there, should start with `awseb`, select it **=>** It'll take you to the Security Group Inbound page by default **=>** Edit **=>** remove `Inbound Port 80` and `Inbound Port 443`

**If your environment is using a Load Balancer**

Go the EB Dashboard, click on your app **=>** go to `Configuration` on the left **=>** click on `Load Balancer` settings icon on the top left. There you will see `Listener port: 80`. Click `80` and switch it to `OFF`. You can also do this to `Secure listener port: 443` which should *not* actually be on by default.

**Update:**

To dynamically update your Security Group Incomming Traffic, use the EC2 SDK's `authorizeSecurityGroupIngress` Documented [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#authorizeSecurityGroupIngress-property).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to do this on single-instance environments, i.e. without load balancers? I'm worried that rebuilding the environment could inadvertently create a security risk.

Comment: A security risk?
And yup, do the first two methods. The second method is only if you have a load balancer running

Comment: "Security risk" being that people outside the security group can access the service if the environment is rebuilt.

Comment: If you're using some sort of your own secuirty, I suppose so but if you want to rebuild the environment, you could just add the same security group the previous one had. Did the security group stuff work out for you?

Comment: I guess what I mean is this. Let's say I want to have a service that can delete users from my application. Instead of using authentication, I would like to rely on a security group to prevent unauthorized access to the service. The first time I create the service, I manually edit the automatically created EB security groups to block traffic on port 80. However, if the environment needs to be rebuilt, then EB automatically generates new security groups that allow traffic on port 80. This is a security risk. If the person rebuilding the environment doesn't know, then there will be a huge hole.

Comment: Ahh I see. Documentation my friend. Confluence and Readmes haha. Were you able to get the ports disabled though? Also if you create the EB environment in a VPC or *as* a VPC (if it's the first private instance), external access will be off by default. Check out VPCs. It sounds like you're creating default servers and are actually looking to set up VPC servers. They *could* have ingress traffic over port 80 but nothing will happen because you have to connect it to an Internet gateway.

Comment: Even with documentation there are still security risks. No matter how fast you are, rebuilding the environment will always expose your services to the outside world for some time. This will give attackers a short window into the system.

Comment: @Max have you found a proper solution to this problem since that does not involve manual patch up work afterwards?